# iOS local notifications and automatic discarding of the-not-the-soonest-firing-64

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

So with iOS local notifications, you have this:

```
Each application on a device is limited to the soonest-firing 64 scheduled local
notifications. The operating system discards notifications that exceed this limit. It 
considers a recurring notification to be a single notification.
```

Is there an easy way to figure out when adding a notification, when another notification that got pushed out of the 64-soonest range, got "discarded"? Does one need to manually loop through all the notifications, and "guess" the notification which fires the last, to figure out which will be removed?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, local notifications are returned in an NSArray that is ordered by fireDate, so you just have to grab the last one.

```
NSArray *array = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *willBeRemoved = [array lastObject];
```

Hope that helps :)